# QSqlQuery::record::value::toInt() produces unexpected result

Tags: sqlite, qt5

I am making a library management software using Qt5 and sqlite3. I defined issueBook function to issue a book to a user. This is the code for issueBook:

```
void MainWindow :: onIsssueDetailsEntered(const QString &name, const QDate &date)
{

QSqlQuery query;

if(!query.exec("SELECT QUANTITY FROM allBooks WHERE UID = " + uid + ";") )
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Oops!", "Selection failed: " + query.lastError().text());
else
{
    int val = query.record().value(0).toInt();

    if(val <= 0)
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Oops!", "You have no book in stock to issue");
    else
    {
        query.exec("UPDATE allBooks SET QUANTITY = " + QString :: number(val - 1) + " WHERE UID = " + uid + ";");

        query.prepare("INSERT INTO log (STUDENT, UID, ISSUED) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

        query.addBindValue(name);
        query.addBindValue(uid);
        query.addBindValue(date.toString(Qt::RFC2822Date));

        if(!query.exec())
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(this, "Oops!", query.lastError().text());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Line 5 when executed from terminal shows output of 1. but val has value 0. So, the program shows error message "You have no books in stock to issue". I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replaced `int val = query.record().value().toInt()` with

```
int val;

if(query.next())
    val = query.value(0).toInt();
```

And it worked